# Drag and drop in Selenium is not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There isnt any error shown in the console. The following code is used.

```
WebElement asd=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='div1']"));
    WebElement dest=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='drag1']"));
    Point point = dest.getLocation();
    int xcord = point.getX();
    System.out.println("Element's Position from left side Is "+xcord +" pixels.");
    int ycord = point.getY();
    System.out.println("Element's Position from top side Is "+ycord +" pixels.");
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);

            act.clickAndHold(asd);
    act.moveToElement(dest, 8, 164);
    act.perform();
    Thread.sleep(250);
    act.release(dest);
    act.perform();
```

Comment: does the `sout` correct print? and can you check that the elements exists?

Comment: @Gp_1993 When you say `There isnt any error shown` how do you conclude `Drag and drop in Selenium is not working` ? Thanks

Comment: The element does exist and the value is available in sout :)

Comment: @Gp_1993 I think the Selenium documentation refers to pull in at-least more than 50% of the drag-able element into the destination. Can you update why are you hard-coding `8` & `164` as in `moveToElement(dest, 8, 164);`? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
WebElement asd= = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='div1']"));
WebElement dest = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='drag1']"));
Actions action1 = new Actions(driver);
action1.dragAndDrop(asd, dest).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code . I hope it will help you :

```
        WebElement asd= = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='div1']"));
        WebElement dest = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='drag1']"));
        Actions action1 = new Actions(driver);
        action1.clickAndHold(asd).moveToElement(dest).release(asd).build().perform();
```

Comment: Nope not yet...There isnt any error ..But still It doesnt work ..DOnt know why

Comment: can you update your code once again with my code in it